# Sortable jQuery UI how to add custom placeholder to empty lists

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to make a dashboard with sortable plugin. I've set up two different columns as sortable-list. What I want to do is: if the sortable-list is empty, if there are no widgets in it, I want to add a custom description field here. With jQuery, I can add a description to an empty div, but that description is permanent. I want the code to run continuously.

```
<div id="draggable-area" class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-xl-8 col-xs-8">
    <div class="sortable-list">
      <div class="sortable-item">
        <div class="main-title">
          <span class="pull-left">
            <span class="trade-icon"></span>
            <h1>Trades</h1>
          </span>
          <i class="fa fa-arrows drag" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <span class="pull-right">
            <a href="#"><strong>All new trades</strong></a>
          </span>
        </div>

        <div class="trade-posts">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 col-xl-4 col-xs-4">
    <div class="sortable-list">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code checking empty divs.

```
$(".sortable-list").each(function(){
function isEmpty( el ){
      return !$.trim(el.html())
  }
  if (isEmpty($(this))) {
    $("<div class='empty'><span>You can drop here.</span></div>").appendTo(this);
  }
});
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please explain little more:
Do you mean that when there is no elements to sort available inside a container, you want to display message inside this container?

Comment: Yeah @Nitesh that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I have understood, I tried to make changes.
I have changed the way you were using each function.

Please check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rmSgx/386/

Code:

```
function insertContent(){
  var $list = $(".sortable-list");
  $list.each(function(index,li){
    if($(li).text().trim().length === 0){
     $(li).text("Please insert here...");
    }
  })
}
```

If there is something else that you want, please clarify more. I will do required changes.

Comment: I updated my question @Nitesh, thank yo for your help. I added a gif. I hope that I can explain the problem well.